# Substitute codes for names

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a report written out of SQL that I am pulling into an Excel workbook (hence the multiple tags) with Patient Information that I want to filter into other values. For instance my workbook looks something like this:

```
Name          Acct #          Date
Shmo,Joe      12345           1/1/15
Shmo,Joe      49738           1/2/15
Shmo,Joe      19725           2/1/15
Smith,Jane    59785           1/5/15
Smith,Jane    36740           3/2/15
```

This is all well and good until now when they want this data filtered to "remove" the patient name but retain that multiple accounts are associated with a patient. For example, I would like a piece of code that will change the above to:

```
Name          Acct #          Date
Patient 1     12345           1/1/15
Patient 1     49738           1/2/15
Patient 1     19725           2/1/15
Patient 2     59785           1/5/15
Patient 2     36740           3/2/15
```

I'm hoping if it can be done either in SQL or in Excel. Even if it just a unique number (1, 2, etc.) without the "Patient" in front would be great.

Comment: Are the patient names always in order? Will Joe ever show up between Jane?

Comment: @findwindow Yes, they will always be in order. My SQL Query is designed to ORDER BY the Name field.

Comment: That makes it much easier. Do a `for` loop down the name column, at each change, replace with previous number +1.

Comment: on sql server you can use count to give a number and concat to add the patient `concat('Patient ',count(*) over (partition by Name))`

Comment: Don't think if it as 'replacing' the patient's name; think of it as adding a new identifier, based on @ScottCraner's suggestion above, and hiding the original name request from the results pulled into Excel.

Comment: @findwindow I'm going to have to look into the `for` loop, as I've never done one before.

Comment: @ScottCraner I followed your suggestion and didn't get exactly what I was looking for. It seemed to work (First Name was Patient 1) but the second name showed up as `Patient 5` and then when it got to the third patient it came back as `Patient 1` again.

Comment: Any reason you need VBA? You could create a quick Vlookup table and a helper column (say col. B) and use a Vlookup formula in column B, then replace that over "A".

Comment: My bad sorry use this instead. `concat('Patient ',DENSE_RANK() over(order by name) )`

Comment: @ScottCraner This worked like a charm! Please post as an additional answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for Excel. This adds a new column in D. Change to a different column if necessary.

```
Sub Zach()

Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = WorkSheets("Sheet6").Cells(WorkSheets("Sheet6").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'change sheet
n = 1
S = 2

For i = 2 To lastRow

    If Cells(i + 1, 1) <> Cells(i, 1) Then
        Range(Cells(S, 4), Cells(i, 4)).Value = "Patient " & n
        n = n + 1
        S = i + 1
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I changed it to replace what was in the A Column instead since I no longer needed the names in this instance. Marking this as the answer since your code was thorough and you got me what I needed so quickly.

Comment: Yea, I avoid deleting data unless user specifically asks. Macro actions cannot be undone.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Sql Server then the following will give the alias you want:

```
concat('Patient ',DENSE_RANK() over(order by name))
```

Comment: I would have marked this as the answer if I had it two minutes sooner, but even so this code works great in Sql. I will be using this in the future for sure. +1

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports *Windowed Aggregate Functions* you can utilize DENSE_RANK like:

```
'Patient ' || CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if mine does or not. When I tried it though, I received an error stating I had incorrect syntax near the second pipe.

Comment: @ZachFord: You tagged `SQL` and this answer **is**` Standard SQL, but you probably use `MySQL` (due to `concat`)

Comment: you'll have to excuse my ignorance, as I am quite new to this, but I tagged `SQL` because I am running a query using the language. Isn't `MySQL` just a database management system that _uses_ `SQL` (the language) to query out of it? Why would it make a difference if I'm using writing it out of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (which I am)?

Comment: @ZachFord: Most DBMSes actually use more or less some proprietary extensions to Standard SQL (and `CONCAT` is not part of the standard). In `MS SQL Server` (this is the actual DBMS, Management Studio is just a client) there are two variations for string concatenation, `+` and `concat`, both are non-Standard, similar to `CAST` vs. `CONVERT`. Btw, it's not your ignorance, it's MS trying to make people believe that `SQL` primarily relates to their product.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I will definitely have to do some more digging to satisfy my own curiosity.